# cannot append array to npy file

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np 
with open("stest.npy","ab") as x:
    for i in range(10):
        np.save(x,np.ones((2,2)))

f = np.load("stest.npy")
print(f)
```

the result I got is (2,2) which means the results are overwritten.Why cant I append to the npy file.I want to append huge number of arrays to the file.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not designed to hold many arrays.

Comment: Is there any alternatives so that I can continuosly append more arrays

Comment: Look into using HDF5 via h5py.

Comment: Actually your `save` did save 10 arrays, one after the other.  Your `load` just read the first one.  To see all ten you have to do a repeated `load`, just as you did the repeated `save`.